# How regex a empty string in python?

Tags: python, regex

I want that find empty tags, here is a example

```
txt ="<lol1><><lol2>"
rgx = "<([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)>"
print re.findall(rgex, txt)
```

I get this

```
['lol1', 'lol2']
```

I want

```
['lol1', '', 'lol2']
```

How I can do this with regex?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `rgx = "<([a-zA-Z_0-9]*)>"`

The key point is using `*`, which means "zero or more of the preceding", where you're using `+`, which means "one or more".

Answer (score 0):

no need regex

```
>>> s="txt ="<lol1><><lol2>"
>>> for i in txt.split(">"):
...     if "<" in i:
...        print i[i.find("<")+1:]
...
lol1

lol2
>>> [i[i.find("<")+1:] for i in txt.split(">") if "<" in i ]
['lol1', '', 'lol2']
```

Comment: `i[i.find("<")+1:]` can be replaced with `i.lstrip('<')` or `i[1:]`. `if "<" in i` can be eliminated or replaced with `if i.startswith("<")`, which is more efficient and to the point.

Comment: I know, but is a more complicated code that the one here, thanks.